# Teamcity checkout directories

Tags: teamcity

I'm wondering how teamcity handles the checkout for multiple configurations. They recommend to use the `Auto` option where the checkout directory is shared between all configurations. Then, what happens if one configuration is currently building, and another is going to checkout? I think I really have to set different directories for these? Also if different configurations have run, their output gets overwritten by each other.

*As a side-note: we have one project with three configurations, namely Continuous, Nightly and Weekly. Maybe I have to split them into different projects?! But on the other hand I think different projects are more suitable for different branches or so.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teamcity won't ever run two builds on one agent at the same time, so you'll never have the case where two builds try to use the same directory at the same time.

But that aside, Teamcity *will* use a different directory for configurations with different VCS roots; it'll only share if they have the same VCS roots with the same checkout rules. But that shouldn't cause you any problems, if you set things up right.

> Also if different configurations have run, their output gets overwritten by each other.

You shouldn't be relying on files being in that directory. If you need access to the files, you should publish them as [artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Artifact), and set the build configurations that need them to have [artifact dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Artifact+Dependencies) on the artifacts.

> As a side-note: we have one project with three configurations, namely Continuous, Nightly and Weekly. Maybe I have to split them into different projects?!

You shouldn't have to; why would you need to split them? They can run fine in the same project, but you can move them into separate ones if you prefer.

Comment: Well, your're right. I didn't consider that on one agent only one build can be run at the same time. Therefore my other statements really don't make any sense :D It just felt strange at the first time. So I was just asking :) Thanks!

Comment: No worries; it's a little confusing to wrap your head around everything about Teamcity. The point about artifacts is still useful, though: it's a way to pass files from one build configuration to another without requiring the build configurations to be on the same agent.